# Артефакты при отправке HTML письма из Битрикс 24

Tags: html, css, email

Всем привет! При отправке HTML письма через рассылку Битрикс24 возникает такая проблема, перед началом письма появляется этот код. В чем может быть причина?
[image: Собственно сама ошибка]

Прикладываю начало кода письма, где как раз встречается этот код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" style="width:100%;font-family:lato, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0">
 <head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"> 
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"> 
  <title>Title.Title</title> 
  <!--[if (mso 16)]>
    <style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none;}
    </style>
    <![endif]--> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><style type="text/css">sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]--> 
  <!--[if !mso]>--> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arsenal&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <!--<![endif]-->
```

UPD. Определил, что строчка sup пропадает после добавления type="text/css" в style.
96 - остается,
4 точки (ul) пропадают, если удалить link со шрифтами.